# Looking alterantive font similar to "Visigoth"

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

Im looking for an alternative similar to the font **Visigoth** by Arthur Baker, but with smother and less rough. Similar to the Sonic and the Secret rings in how smoothness.

and the Secret rings logo
[image: and the Secret rings logo]

Comment: Use a service such as WhatTheFont - it should be able to find similar fonts for you.